# Displaying database table using JQuery

Tags: php, postgresql

**Problem**

I have a database full of food and drink, at the moment it is being displayed using a basic table but it doesn't look great nor does it look professional. I understand that I can use JQuery but I don't seem to get it to work.

**Question**

Using this code that implements my table:

```
<?php
    $conn = pg_connect("host=db.dcs.aber.ac.uk port=5432
                                    dbname=teaching user=csguest password=********");
    $res  = pg_query($conn, "SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price FROM food
        ORDER BY Category ASC");
        echo "<table id=\"myTable\" border='1'>";
        while ($a = pg_fetch_row($res)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($res); $j++) {
                                    echo "<td>" . $a[$j] . "</td>";
                                }
            echo "<td><form id='cart' name='cart' method='POST' action='addToBasket.php'>
            <input type='submit' name='Select' id='Select' value='Add To Basket'>
            </form></td>";
            echo "</tr>\n";
            }
        echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

How would I use JQuery to affect, for example, the price of the products. Could i simply use data-sort to affect the float values in the table? I am confused as other examples are not echoing the table, they're just creating one.

Comment: Why using jQuery at all?  How do you want to affect your values?

Comment: I highly recommend using [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) if you wanna go with the jQuery path.

Comment: Don't use JQuery. SImply make your table nicer by adding some CSS.

Comment: Am i able to separate each row using CSS?

Comment: You can using something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child